# Using VLookup or Index/Match from two tabs in excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I wanted to perform the following using a VLOOKUP:

- If value in column E (*MMA Uploader* sheet tab) is found in column B (*MMA Product List* sheet tab)...
- Paste value of column A (*MMA Product List* sheet tab) into column D (*MMA Uploader* sheet tab)

Here is a visual example:

- MMA Uploader tab:

[image]

- MMA Product List tab:

[image]

- Places appropriate ID (in MMA Uploader tab) since VLOOKUP has found a matching name:

[image]

This is what I have so far with my VLOOKUP function (testing it in cell D2 of the MMA Uploader tab):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&E2&"*",'MMA Product List'!$A:$B,1,FALSE), "N/A")
```

This is what I have so far with my INDEX MATCH function (testing it in cell D2 of the MMA Uploader tab):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('MMA Product List'!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&E3&"*", 'MMA Product List'!$B:$B,0)), "N/A")
```

Neither of the functions I wrote above result in a value, they both return #N/A.

As always, thank you for your help!

Comment: `VLOOKUP` only searches the first column and returns any column to the right of it, the result you want is on the left. Look into [`INDEX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) and [`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad makes sense, thank you. That's why I was questioning why this solution didn't work either:

=VLOOKUP("*"&E2&"*",'MMA Product List'!A:B,1,FALSE)

This would return #N/A, even though the lookup does exist (since you mentioned VLOOKUP only searches column to the right of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using VBA, you can use `Range.Find` and work with the sheet objects directly, instead of going through formulas to retrieve values.

Here is an example of a simple loop through column E, using `Range.Find` to look in the other sheet's column B and copy over values:

```vb
Dim wsUp As Worksheet
Set wsUp = Sheets("MMA Uploader")

Dim wsPL As Worksheet
Set wsPL = Sheets("MMA Product List")

'Finding the last non-blank cell in Uploader Column E
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = wsUp.Cells(wsUp.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop though Uploader Column E from row 2 till the last non-blank cell
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To LastRow
  Dim rFind As Range
  'Looking in Product List column B for each value of Uploader column E
  Set rFind = wsPL.Columns(2).Find(what:=wsUp.Cells(i, 5), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
  
  'If a value is found, then copy from column A into Uploader column D
  If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
    wsUp.Cells(i, 4).Value = rFind.Offset(0, -1).Value
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you @Toddleson, this works great as a VBA macro. The solution to do this via excel formula would be:

=IFERROR(INDEX('MMA Product List'!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&E3&"*", 'MMA Product List'!$B:$B,0)), "N/A")

But, marking your answer as the solution.